# Seagate external hard disk not detecting in my ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a 2 TB Seagate external hard disk. In my ubuntu 16.04 it stopped detecting.
I tried mounting this drive in another ubuntu 16.04 & Windows 7. In both machines, it is working.

When I plug it into my desktop, the light on the disk turns on. But I don't see the drive in my system.

The output of `sudo parted -l` shows only the internal drives.
I tried running `ls /dev/ | grep sd` but same results.

But in the output of `usb-devices` I can see the  device.

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=01 Dev#= 21 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bc2 ProdID=ab26 Rev=01.08
S:  Manufacturer=Seagate
S:  Product=BUP Slim BK
S:  SerialNumber=NA9KLFBN
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=896mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 1 #EPs= 4 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=62 Driver=uas
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Dose it show up with `lsblk -f`?. Also, 16.04 is reaching End-Of-Life in a few days.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  -f` as you connect the drive.

Comment: it says ```usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?```

Comment: But then it shouldn't have worked in other machines.

Comment: also getting this error ```io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1```

Comment: could be a problem with modul uas.  Create `/etc/modprobe.d/uas.conf` with content `options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:ab26:u`  then update your initrids  `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` reboot.

Comment: @nobody it worked.